# Are there any experimental data for the behavior of quantum systems in non-inertial frames?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-gravity

Are there any experimental data for the behavior of quantum systems in non-inertial frames? I could find theoretical research dealing with quantum mechanics in non-inertial frames. But, I wonder, if there has been carried out any experiment to study quantum processes involving non-inertial observers. If yes, what were the results?

Comment: Well, there's [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.96.063401), but I don't know if it'll satisfy your requirements. More generally, *any* experiment on an inertial frame can be analyzed from a non-inertial frame, but that doesn't really introduce anything new. Unless you're actually taking data from two different observers and comparing them, it's all just post-analysis mumbo-jumbo at some level.

Comment: The entire phenomenon of nuclear magnetic resonance (NMR) is based on a quantum-mechanical magnetic moment viewed from a rotating frame: http://mriquestions.com/rotating-frame.html. So presumably all NMR experiments fit your description.

Comment: A frame of references is an agreement on how to measure position and time. Nothing more, nothing less. (We often define frames as being connected to a observer or vehicle, but that's just how we agree to measure.) As such they can not have any relationship to what actually happens, just to what your instruments read.